# Comparar COUNT de duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-select

Tenho duas tabelas e devo retornar o total da tabela com mais dados, estou fazendo assim:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ((select count(*) as `familiar` from tb.familiar)) > 
                 ((select count(*) as `personal` from tb.personal))
                  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS total
```

Dessa forma funciona, quando a tabela `familiar` é maior retorna 0 e quando não retorna 1. Mas como retorno o valor do `COUNT`? Pois quando coloco o apelidos (`familiar` ou `personal`) do count dá erro de sintaxe, por exemplo:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ((select count(*) as `familiar` from tb.familiar)) > 
                 ((select count(*) as `personal` from tb.personal))
                  THEN familiar ELSE personal END AS total
```

Da o seguinte erro:

> Unknown column 'familiar' in 'field list'

Comment: Você poderia colocar os código que estão com problemas, talvez isso auxilie na resposta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você teria que repetir todo o código dos dois `Select count...` dentro do `THEN` e do `ELSE`.

Ou...

Você pode fazer um subselect:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN FAMILIAR > PERSONAL THEN FAMILIAR ELSE PERSONAL END AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        (select count(*) from tb.familiar) AS FAMILIAR,
        (select count(*) from tb.personal) AS PERSONAL
) X
```

Comment: Só colocaria depois do `END` um `AS TOTAL` pra coluna receber um nome.

Comment: Verdade! Editei para ter o nome. Obrigado @Gumball